# Use find to search in hidden dirs

Tags: linux, find

Need to collect all git configs, I use

```
find / -type f -name '.gitconfig'
```

But also I need find out all locals 'config' under hidden .git dirs

Comment: find does search in `.foo`

Comment: /some_name/.git/config  - i have to find this **config** file

Comment: Yes, I understand. And standard find will find it.

Comment: i tryed find / -type f -name 'config' -type d -name '.git' dont works :(

Comment: What is your Linux distro and version of find? What you describe is unusual, people usually ask the opposite (e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901738/find-command-search-only-non-hidden-directories))

Comment: find (GNU findutils) 4.5.9
Features enabled: D_TYPE O_NOFOLLOW(enabled) LEAF_OPTIMISATION FTS(FTS_CWDFD) CBO(level=2)

Comment: What Linux distribution?

Answer (score -1):

This command:

```
ls -a
```

should do it.

Comment: That just lists all files and directories within the current dirctory, including hidden ones. It does not help with the use of `find` (e.g. for a recursive search, for a specific filename) in any way.